# MS Project get the field name

Tags: c#, ms-project

I'm trying to get the type or the name of my field, I can do it with VBA by using:

```
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList.Item(1)
```

(1 because I just need the first which is selected).

But this method doesn't exist in Visual Studio, I have others but not this one - I do have:

```
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList.Count
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList.Application
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList.Parent
```

Someone knows what I could do to get back it in Visual Studio?

Or do have you any idea how could I get the type of field? Because if I have the type (Date, String, ...), I could advance on my project

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Application.ActiveSelection.FieldNameList[0]
```

This should be your your first selected first name object.